# How to find this improper integral? $\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How to calculate improper integral? $$\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx}.$$

Comment: Cross-posted from http://mathoverflow.net/questions/170357/integraf-of-sinx-sqrtx-from-0-to-pi. Are you the same user?

Comment: Yes, you said to post it here.

Comment: Please do not create a **new** account on M.SE for cross-posting a question.

Comment: it's same (google) account.

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x}dx=\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\qquad\quad;\quad\qquad\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}xdx=\frac\pi2$$ $$-2<n<0\quad=>\quad\int_0^\infty x^n\sin x~dx=n!\cdot\cos\bigg(n\cdot\frac\pi2\bigg).$$

Comment: @Lucian. I am not sure of the result for your first integral. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: They are all correct. $($Note that the upper limit is infinity, not $\pi)$.

Comment: @Lucian. Oooops ! I am sorry and you are perfectly right (as usual). Cheers. :)

Comment: Sometimes ago, I [evaluated that integral](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/828637/85343).

Answer (score 5):

This is related to Fresnel integrals $$\int{\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx}=\sqrt{2 \pi } S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2 x}{\pi }} \right)$$ $$\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx}=\sqrt{2 \pi } S\left(\sqrt{2}\right) \simeq 1.789662939$$

Without special function, you can compute the integral starting with the Taylor development of $\sin(x)$ which then leads to  $$\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx}=\int_{0}^{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2 n+\frac{1}{2}}}{(2 n+1)!}~dx=2\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ (-1)^n \pi ^{2 n}}{(4 n+3) (2 n+1)!}$$ Using $5$ terms, the result is $1.789604144$ while using $10$ terms leads to $1.789662939$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
With $\ds{x \equiv {\pi t^{2} \over 2}}$:

> \begin{align}
> \color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin\pars{x} \over \root{x}}\,\dd x}&=
> \root{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\root{2}}\sin\pars{\pi t^{2} \over 2}\,\dd t
> =\color{#66f}{\large\root{2\pi}{\rm S}\pars{\root{2}}}
> \approx 1.7897
> \end{align}

wehe $\ds{{\rm S}\pars{x}}$ is a
[Fresnel Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).